# Ruby/Mechanize Any way to drain RAM? -> failed to allocate memory

Tags: ruby, variables, memory, mechanize, ram

I've built a code which vote for me on a website...

The Ruby script works quite well but after few minuts this script stop with this errors : [link of the screen-shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PuyHC.png)

**So I've inspected the windows task manager and the memory alocate to the ruby.exe grow after each loop !**

here is the incriminate peace of code :

```
class VoteWebsite
        def self.main
        agent = Mechanize.new
        agent.user_agent_alias = 'Windows Mozilla'
    while $stop!=true
        page = agent.get 'http://website.com/vote.php'
        reports_divs = page.search(".//div[@class='Pad1Color2']")
        tds = reports_divs.search("td")
        i = 3;j = 0;ouiboucle=0;voteboucle=0
        while i < tds.length
            result = tds[i].to_s.scan(/<font class="ColorRed"><b>(.*?) :<\/b><\/font>/)
            type = result[0].to_s[2..-3]
            k=i
            case type
            when "Type of vote"
                j= i+1;i += 4
                result2 = tds[j].to_s.scan(/<div id="btn(.*?)">/)           
                id = result2[0].to_s[2..-3]
                monvote=define_vote($vote_type, tds[k].to_s, $vote_auto)
                page2 = agent.get 'http://website.com/AJAX_Vote.php?id='+id+'&vote='+monvote
                voteboucle+=1
                .
                .
                .
            else
                .
                .
                .
            end
        end     
    end
    end
end
VoteWebsite.main
```

I think that declaring all the variables inside the method to Global variable should fix this probleme but the code is quite big and there is planty of variables inside this method.

**So is there any way (any Ruby instruction) to drain all this variable at the end of each loop ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem came, in fact, from the history of mechanize [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7191752/ruby-mechanize-probleme-of-ram-erasing-instensiation-of-agent-get-method/7433442#7433442) or the [`Mechanize::History.clear`](http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/Mechanize/History.html#method-i-clear) method or even just set the [`Mechanize::History.max_size`](http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/Mechanize/History.html#max_size=) attribute to a reasonable value.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'mechanize'

class GetContent
    def initialize url
        agent = Mechanize.new
    agent.user_agent_alias = 'Windows Mozilla'
    agent.history.max_size=0
    while true
            page = agent.get url
        end
    end
end

myPage = GetContent.new('http://www.nypost.com/')
```

hope it helps !

Answer (score 1):

You can always force the garbage collector to kick in:

```
GC.start
```

As a note, this doesn't look very Ruby. Packing multiple statements on to one line using `;` is bad form, and using `$` type variables is probably a relic of it being ported from something else.

Remember that `$`-prefixed variables are *global variables* in Ruby and can cause tons of problems if used carelessly and should be reserved for very specific circumstances. The best alternative is an `@`-prefixed instance variable, or if you must, a declared `CONSTANT`.

Comment: Thanks a lot I'll tray this asap...

I'know that my programming in ruby is quite dirty. You're not the first to tell me that.

Thanks a lot for this useful help