# Ruby/Mechanize "failed to allocate memory". Erasing instantiation of 'agent.get' method?

Tags: ruby, mechanize, ram

I've got a little problem about leaking memory in a Mechanize Ruby script.

I "while loop" multiple web pages access forever and memory increase a lot on each loop. That created a "failed to allocate memory" after minutes and made script exit.

In fact, it seems that the `agent.get` method instantiate and hold the result even if I assign the result to the same "local variable" or even a "global variable".
So I tried to assign `nil` to the variable after last used and before reusing the same name variable. But it seems that previous `agent.get` results are still in memory and really don't know how to drain RAM to make my script using a roughly stable amount of memory after hours?

Here are two peace of code : *(stay on "enter" key and see the Ruby allocated RAM growing)*

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'mechanize'

agent = Mechanize.new
agent.user_agent_alias = 'Windows Mozilla'
GC.enable
#puts GC.malloc_allocations
while gets.chomp!="stop"
    page = agent.get 'http://www.nypost.com/'
    puts "agent.object_id  : "+agent.object_id.to_s
    puts "page.object_id  : "+page.object_id.to_s
    page=nil
    puts "page.object_id  : "+page.object_id.to_s
    page = agent.get 'http://www.nypost.com/'
    puts "page.object_id  : "+page.object_id.to_s
    page=nil
    puts "page.object_id  : "+page.object_id.to_s
    puts local_variables
    GC.start
    puts local_variables
    #puts GC.malloc_allocations
end
```

And with global variable instead :

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'mechanize'

agent = Mechanize.new
agent.user_agent_alias = 'Windows Mozilla'
while gets.chomp!="stop"
    $page = agent.get 'http://www.nypost.com/'
    puts "agent.object_id  : "+agent.object_id.to_s
    puts "$page.object_id  : "+$page.object_id.to_s
    $page = agent.get 'http://www.nypost.com/'
    puts "$page.object_id  : "+$page.object_id.to_s
    #puts local_variables
    #puts global_variables
end
```

In other languages the variable is re-affected and allocated memory stay stable. why ruby doesn't? How can I force instances to garbage?

**Edit :**
Here is an other example using Object as Ruby is an Object Oriented language but result is exactly the same : memory grow again and again...

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'mechanize'

$agent = Mechanize.new
$agent.user_agent_alias = 'Windows Mozilla'
class GetContent
    def initialize url
        while true
            @page = $agent.get url
            remove_instance_variable(:@page)
        end
    end
end
myPage = GetContent.new('http://www.nypost.com/')
```

**My Answer** (not enough reputation to do it properly)

Ok so !

It seems that [`Mechanize::History.clear`](http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/Mechanize/History.html#method-i-clear) greatly solves this problem of memory leak.

here is the last Ruby code modified if you want to test before and after...

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'mechanize'

$agent = Mechanize.new
$agent.user_agent_alias = 'Windows Mozilla'
class GetContent
    def initialize url
        while true
            @page = $agent.get url
            $agent.history.clear
        end
    end
end
myPage = GetContent.new('http://www.nypost.com/')
```

Comment: Why are you looping and getting the page multiple times, exactly?

Comment: Because it's not the nypost.com but I get the content of a page and do some votes by recovering vote_id and launching other vote php blank pages... So I got to refresh the main page after some `sleep xxx` and RAM memory grow up on each loop even if `sleep xxx` reducing the effect of growing, my script will always end with the `failed to allocate memory` error and it should not... I really don't understand how to prevent the `agent.get` method instentiation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestion is setting agent.max_history = 0. As mentioned in the list of linked issues.

This will keep a history entry from even being added, instead of using #clear.

Here is the modified version of the other answer

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'mechanize'

$agent = Mechanize.new
$agent.user_agent_alias = 'Windows Mozilla'
$agent.max_history = 0
class GetContent
    def initialize url
        while true
            @page = $agent.get url
        end
    end
end
myPage = GetContent.new('http://www.nypost.com/')
```

Comment: yep this is what I done soon after but I just can not update my answers each time I progress in ruby... Your right !

Answer (score 1):

Ok so ! *(had enough reputation to answer my owns questions properly)*

It seems that [`Mechanize::History.clear`](http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/Mechanize/History.html#method-i-clear) greatly solves this problem of memory leak.

here is the last Ruby code modified if you want to test before and after...

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'mechanize'

$agent = Mechanize.new
$agent.user_agent_alias = 'Windows Mozilla'
class GetContent
    def initialize url
        while true
            @page = $agent.get url
            $agent.history.clear
        end
    end
end
myPage = GetContent.new('http://www.nypost.com/')
```

Comment: I cannot thank you enough. This tip has *significantly* reduce the time it took my script to download each consecutive file and reduced the memory usage. The Mechanize still leaks it seems, but not as bad as before.